# Syntax creating a Table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am trying to create a database to learn sql but i have a synatx problem i dont know from where it come :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mybase

CREATE TABLE mybase.user(
    user_id     INT     NOT NULL,
    username    VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE mybase.task(
    task_id     INT     NOT NULL,
    title   VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    begin   DATE    DEFAULT DATE,
    end     DATE    DEFAULT NULL,
    status  DEFAULT NOT STARTED
);

CREATE TABLE mybase.user_has_task(
    fk_user_id  INT,
    fk_task_id  INT
);ter code here
```

I do the following command : `cat mybase.sql | sudo mysql -u root -p`

And i have a syntax error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: `status  DEFAULT NOT STARTED` is most certainly not a valid column declaration.

Comment: You are missing a terminator after the create database statement.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax it's clear.

You have a syntax error, you are missing ; in the create database statement.

Also  `status  DEFAULT NOT STARTED` this is not OK.

I think you are trying to do this:

```
status VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "NOT STARTED"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for the quick answers! I searched and made an overall change :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mybase;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mybase.user(
    user_id     INT              NOT NULL,
    username    VARCHAR(25)      NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(100)     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mybase.task(
    task_id     INT          NOT NULL,
    title   VARCHAR(25)      NOT NULL,
    begin   DATETIME    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    end     DATETIME    DEFAULT NULL,
    status  CHAR(11)    DEFAULT "NOT STARTED"
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mybase.user_has_task(
    fk_user_id  INT,
    fk_task_id  INT
);
```

And it works now thanks !